# Checking if an argument is passed in variadic macros in C

Tags: c, gcc, c99, variadic-macros

For cleaner error handling I use a macro (it uses C99 and GCC extensions); the behavior is like standard `assert`:

```
#define A(cond, msg, ...) ({ \
        if (!(cond)) { \
                if (msg) \
                        say(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
                else \
                        say("Error at file %s, function %s, line %u: %s", \
                                __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, #cond); \
                A_RETURN(); \
        } \
})
```

where `say` is a formatted output. And use it like that:

```
#undef A_RETURN
#define A_RETURN() ({ fclose(f); free(p); return false; })

A(foo() != FOO_ERROR, 0);
A(bar() != BAR_ERROR, "bar failed");
```

When I don't have a specific error message, I have to write `A(cond, 0)`. But I want just write `A(cond)` in this case. How to modify my `A` macro for this behavior? I.e. I need a way to check if `msg` argument isn't passed to the macro.

Comment: #define A_no_msg(cond) A(cond, NULL)

Comment: You could try do it with some argument counting as detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14674318/817643 The example uses the entire available 64 parameters. You'd only need one. I suggest wholeheartedly that you just use another macro name.

Comment: @selbie: I want a single macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help of [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674318/) I came to the point that you can modify your macro like this.

```
#define A() .... //your macro

#define A_CALC_ARG_IMPL(_1,N,...) N
#define A_CALC_ARG(...) A_CALC_ARG_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,0)

#define A_NEW(...) A(cond, A_CALC_ARG(__VA_RGS__))
```

so your new `A_NEW` macro call will be expanded to `A(cond, 0)` if you don't pass `msg`.

Variadic macro is explained nicely [at this blog](http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the provided link for the *Variadic macro explanation* is now invalid. Could you update your question? Thx & Regards